# OpenCV Histogram Mask

Tags: c#, image, opencv, image-processing

I want to calculate histogram of Image.
I have to use mask. My mask should looks like Black and white image? 
Black to ignore space, and white to calculate?

To create Mask. I replace my white pixels (R>220 & G>220 & B>220) to black, other ones to white.

Am I doing it right?

Comment: Your general understanding of a mask is correct. Your method would be correct if what you're trying to do is calculate the histogram of all the pixels which have values less than 220.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution for making mask is right, if you want to calculate histogram on the parts of image that pixels' value are less than 220 on each channels.
Also be careful not to replace pixels on your original image. Just make a single channel `cv::Mat`, which is the same height and width as original image. Then, fill it's pixels according original image.
You could also make such a mask using `cv::inRange` function:

```
cv::MAT mask;
// make inverted mask in order to avoid masking pure red, green or blue
cv::inRange(original_image, cv::Scalar(220, 220, 220), cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), mask);
// make non-inverted mask
mask = 255 - mask;
```

Comment: If you code that way, you might mask pixels with values like `(0, 0, 255)`, which are not white. it will happen because the logic in `cv::inRange` is AND.

Comment: That's exactly what the code is doing. He mentioned that he is looking for white pixels, therefore we must find them first, but he wants them to be masked so we invert previous founded mask.
Look at this image:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/dNLz8pdeIa4fkK5B2
By using `(0-220,0-220,0-220)` bound:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/HvNkQ0XfynRnzsIv2

Comment: I see now, thanks for taking the time---didn't realize OP wanted an inverted mask. I'll delete my comments.